# Salesforce Role Hierarchy Setup Advice

Tags: salesforce

I have a Role Hierarchy Setup with the following

```
CEO
-- Finance
----Department A Managers
------ Department A Users
----Department B Managers
------ Department B Users
```

I then only have 2 objects configured to Private

The problem is, we have certain people (Project Managers) that need to be able to view data from these two objects from different users in both Department A Users or Department B Users.

They should not be able to view data from either Department A Managers or Department B Managers.

Does anyone know how I can set this up to work with the above scenario ?

I've spent a lot of time on this and I am not sure the best approach.

Not sure if it possible, perhaps a trigger can be created (or workflow) to update the sharing rules of the record with the Project Manger? If that is the only solution then it might work.

Also I looked at creating a Sharing Rule but you can only share with a Role or Public Group, not an individual user.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think grouping and sharing is prob your best bet. So group dept.A&B users and group the PMs then share. Or you could add a field to your custom objects and share based on criteria, using the field as a flag, and share to the group of PMs. Maybe I've missed something.